# How to safely downgrade apache version to one not suitable for current gnome state?

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, gnome, gnome3, apt

I want to downgrade `apache2-bin` package from `2.4` version to `2.2.22-1` from some snapshot repository. But there is `gnome-user-share` pack that depends on `apache2-bin 2.4` and, as I understood, the part of `gnome-core` packet. And the last revers-depends on `gnome`.

So I have dependency: `apache2-bin (2.4) < gnome-user-share < gnome-core < gnome`

How can I accurately change version of `apache2-bin` pack to `2.2.22-1` but staying at as less changes as possible in the system (desktop environment)?

Comment: Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43165013/694576